# Conditionally remove comments and post meta in functions.php

Tags: php, child-theme, conditional-content

I'm new to Wordpress and am coming from the point and click world of Joomla! what was easy there now involves some solid php knowledge to replicate in Wordpress ;)

I'm try to conditionally remove post-meta and comments from 3 categories using functions.php

I'm using Woothemes Canvas and my own child theme.

I can remove post-meta globally by using an empty function:

```
function woo_post_meta() {}
```

This works fine but I only want it to work for 3 categories

I know I need to somehow use is_category butI'm not sure of the syntax, I tried

```
if ( is_category(4,5,6) ) {
    function woo_post_meta() {}
}
```

but that doesn't work, i'm not sure how to correctly write a function within a function.

Then how do i also remove comments from those categories? or should I make custom content type to do all this?

Comment: do you have any `apply_filters()` in the original `woo_post_meta()` function?

Comment: Hi Birgie, I'm not sure where to find the original woo_post_meta() function, I looked in theme-functions.php but it isn't mentioned in there. I will keep searching though, thanks

Comment: maybe under `/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/includes/theme-functions.php` ?

Comment: Thanks Birgie, yes there is a theme-functions.php file in there but within that I'm not sure what I'm looking for. This is much more tricky than I though so for the time being I will try and use a custom theme file instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

**a)** Instead of

```
is_category(4,5,6)
```

which checks if a category archive page is being displayed (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)), you can try

```
in_category(4,5,6)
```

or

```
in_category( array(4,5,6) )
```

that checks if the current post is assigned to any of the specified categories (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)).

**b)** You could also try

```
function woo_post_meta() {
    if ( in_category(4,5,6) ) {
        return "";
    }else{
     // the original woo_post_meta()  code here.
    }
}
```

**c)** If the original `woo_post_meta()` contains an output filter, than we could add a custom filter with the above category check.

**d)** If you write your own child theme, you could replace the template tag:

```
   woo_post_meta();
```

with

```
  if ( !in_category(4,5,6) ) {
       woo_post_meta();
  }
```

Comment: Excellent thanks Birgire, you have been an immense help!. I will play around with all of these solutions and bookmark this page as a resource for the future. Thanks again :)